# Trouble with encrypted SD card

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, sd-card

I recently encrypted a SD card with disk utility to secure some of my most precious files, with a password. I then renamed the SD card, and then copied the files to it. The trouble is, that when I unplugged my sd and plugged it back, the password I did set didn't work anymore. I guess it's because I changed the name of my card. I tried many things with the terminal, but I can't get anywhere. Does anybody have an idea that could get me out of this trouble, cause those files are really important to me, I'd be desperate to lose access to them forever.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to step through the process manually using Disk Utility.

First connect the card and then don’t enter anything. Next open Disk Utility and then see if the entire disk is encrypted and how many volumes exist. You can also get this data from the command line:

```
diskutil list
```

Or the information tab in Disk Utility and perhaps the menu item to show all partitions. It’s possible you erased everything but it’s also possible that you just renamed the volume inside the encryption. It’s hard to guess without specifics and some back/forth between you and someone that knows disk partitioning.